# Covering full header with background image

Tags: html, css, header, background-image

In my header, I'm trying to get my background image to cover my full header but nothing I'm doing seems to be fixing it.

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/stock-photo-125301449-1500x822.jpg");
  background-postion: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="header-text">
    <h1>Olivia Cahill</h1>
    <h2>A Collection of Her Art</h2>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
When i say cover, I mean that I want the whole first top part of the page to have the image

Comment: Do you have it in jsfiddle? you know that you can embed css/html right on stackoverflow?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cover'? You want the image to cover the text? Can you clarify slightly.

Comment: The background image is covering the entire size of the header http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpoaWe

Comment: Can you draw what you want the header to look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

While it does kind of throw off the aspect ratio, It appears that this is what you may be looking for:

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/stock-photo-125301449-1500x822.jpg");
  background-postion: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="header-text">
    <h1>Olivia Cahill</h1>
    <h2>A Collection of Her Art</h2>   
  </div>
</div>
```

This is ***CSS3***'s background sizing expression. By specifying 100% twice we are essentially saying that we want: 100%(Width) x 100%(Height).

Comment: well now no matter what the image isnt even showing up, after I deleted my original code. Ill try a different image and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body
{
margin: 0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
}
header
{
background-image: url("https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/stock-photo-125301449-1500x822.jpg");
background-postion: center center;
background-position-y: 30%;
overflow: hidden;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
color: #F0477F;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.999em;
font-weight: 400;
}

header h2 {

color: #F0477F;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.414em;
font-weight: 400;

}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>Olivia Cahill</h1>
        <h2>A Collection of Her Art</h2>
</header>
```

Comment: Would my editor (Eclipse) or me using firefox to run it be causing the problem? Because it looks fine in the runs above.

Comment: Your editor can't be the problème, for Firefox i can not be sure but you can try to open your page with Google Chrome and tel lme if the problem persists

Comment: When I opened it using Chrome, no images at all came up, just the text.

Comment: Just edited my answer, try the new code and tell me if that solve your problem

Comment: The second image i have in the body now loads in but the background in the header does not

Comment: I think you have another problem, this code will work with all browsers the same way, and the background header will correctly loaded.

Comment: You can run the code snippet in my answer and you will see the result on full screen, additionally could you post the entire code of your page and explain clearly what's doesn't work so it will be more simple to help you

Comment: Seem to have edited your answer on accident. Sorry. Your answer now has my code so look there

Comment: I saw your edit and your code, but you didn't clearly explain what you want to accomplish

Comment: I want the background image in the header to cover the whole header

Comment: I rewrote your code to make it more clear, retry to run the code snippet and tell me if that's the result you expected

Comment: In the snippet it looks perfect. When I paste it into my project though, the background does not appear

Comment: As i told you, i rewrote your entire code so i retired things which can cause conflicts. You have to begin on a new page then paste it first and after that you can continue to build your project.